# Suppose that there is an $a\in(0,1)$ such that $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leq a^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Prove that $x_n \to x$ for som $x\in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence. Suppose that there is an $a\in(0,1)$ such that $$|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leq a^n$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Prove that $x_n \to x$ for som $x\in \mathbb R$.

I need some help on this one. Or a hint in the right direction. I have I need to use the fact that it is cauchy. Because $a^n, \forall n\in \mathbb N$, seems very to saying $\forall \epsilon$.

Any hint is appreciated!

NOTE: This is very similar to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378062/please-help-prove-that-x-n-is-a-cauchy-sequence-if-x-n1-x-n-leq-cr) but not is not.

Comment: How does it differ from the problem you link to?

Comment: does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699077/proving-that-x-n-n-1-infty-is-a-cauchy-sequence) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822430/limit-of-recurrent-sequence-using-squeeze-theorem-on-strict-inequality) answer your question?

Comment: Read the linked post and replace every $C$ by $1$.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.  Do you understand that every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges?  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#:~:text=Every%20Cauchy%20sequence%20of%20real,the%20least%20upper%20bound%20axiom.) for instance.  Given that, it is clear that all you have to show is that your sequence actually is Cauchy, but that's what the duplicates do.